# Tablesorter issues when used with dragtable plugin.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter plugin for column sorting and dragtable plugin for rearranging the column order. Also, I'll update the table content using ajax on some button clicks.

So the problem here is, when I rearrange the column order using drag and drop and then update the  using ajax, the column sorting is not updated according to the column order. That is, when we click on say Column1, the sorting is done based on data in Column2.

I'm using this piece of code for ajax update.
jQuery("#Table").trigger('updateRows');

I have also tried updating with 
jQuery("#emailListTable").trigger('updateAll');
In this case, column drag and drop stopped working.

Any other way to tell tablesorter plugin that column order is changed?

Plugin details:
TableSorter : http://tablesorter.com/docs/
Dragtable : http://akottr.github.io/dragtable/

Answer (score 1):

Update: version 2.19.0 has been released. It [includes a modified version of the dragtable widget](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/extras/jquery.dragtable.mod.js) - see [the demo here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-dragtable.html).

---

The `updateRows` and `updateAll` methods are not available in the original tablesorter plugin, but are part of my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

In order to get the dragtable widget to work with the fork of tablesorter, you'll need to trigger an `updateAll` event from within the dragtable `persistState` callback function. Try out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4870/) - I had to add some extra HTML & CSS to add a dragable handle so the demo is working 100% (I hope).

CSS

```
.table-handle {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAANAQMAAAC5Li2yAAAABlBMVEXd3d2ZmZl1DvVeAAAADklEQVQI12MAAQcsmAEAEFoBQSzdkZ8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0 1px;
    cursor: move;
}
```

HTML (single header cell example)

```
<th>
    <div class="table-handle"></div>
    <div class="sort">Header</div>
</th>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    var $table = $('table')
        .dragtable({
            dragHandle: '.handle',
            persistState: function (table) {
                // remove div wrapper, or swapped header
                // contents will be replaced
                $table.find('thead .tablesorter-header-inner').contents().unwrap();
                $table.trigger('updateAll', false);
            }
        })
        .tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            selectorSort: '.sort',
            widthFixed: true
        });
});
```

Make sure to also include jQuery UI (jQuery UI css is optional) because it is a dependency of the dragtable widget.

Comment: [Dragtable mod now available](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-dragtable.html)!

Comment: There isn't a feature for drag & drop rows is there? To move a row up or down in the table? Maybe even a button to move it up or down one row at a time?

Comment: @DDDD Check out the [static row widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-static-row.html).

Comment: Is there any support for sticky headers with dragtable?